# How can I prove the following given $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i=1$ and $1\geq p_i \geq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

How can we prove step by step that the minimum value of $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^2$ is $\frac{1}{n}$ and the maximum value is 1 if $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i=1$?

Comment: I guess, $p_i\ge 0$ are assumed, else the maximum is infinity.

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the minimum, we can use the following:
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i^2 & = & \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(p_i-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 \\
& = & \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(p_i-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 
     +2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(p_i-\frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n}
     +\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 \\
& = &  \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(p_i-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 
     +\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i
     -2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 
     +\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 \\
& = &  \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(p_i-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 
      +\frac{2}{n}-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n} \\
& \geq & \frac{1}{n}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
For the maximum:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i^2 + 2\sum_{i<j} p_ip_j = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i\right)^2 = 1
$$
In order to show that the values $\frac{1}{n}$ and $1$ are actually attained, use $p_1=p_2=\ldots = p_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for the minimum and $p_1=1$, $p_2=\ldots = p_n = 0$ for the maximum.